# Weighted average whenever a variance is 0?

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, statistics

So I have data for the number of times a certain event happens. Each column is a different event and each row is one trial. A sample of data would look like

\begin{bmatrix}
1& 4& 7& 6& 5\\
1& 3& 9& 4& 5\\
1& 3& 7& 8& 8\\
\end{bmatrix}

I then collapse this data down into one row, and each number is just the average of the column and has its own variance. I want to take a weighted average of this row and obtain the associated variance as well, but in this example the first number has a variance of 0, and thus the weight would be 1/0. What does one do in a situation like this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics and data science.  It may be better on Math.SE or possibly scientific computing.SE.

Comment: I would suggest to do more measurements, since 3 is a very small amount, which will not give an accurate representation.

Comment: I just used 3 here as a example. In reality its around 100 I think. I mostly have columns of zeros which I suppose I could just ignore since they dont contribute to the mean, but then I got thinking about if a non zero number happens to repeat

Comment: If you aren't seeing statistical variation over that many inputs, then your error is dominated by the instrumental error which you must evaluate or estimate. Basically that bin is considerably wider than the natural width of the signal; this is a sign that a better instrument would help and that more data will not.

Comment: What do you mean by event and trial?  Are you measuring six different parameters (say frequency of six different events in a time span) and a trial is a particular time span? So your data would be that in the first hour, event 1 happened once, event 2 happened 4 times, etc?  It then makes sense to average the different time spans, but why does it make sense to combine the columns?

Comment: In practice, the approach is subjective, but the most popular one is on lines as suggested by @dmckee. You have to see the least count error of the instrument used for the measurement. That's fundamentally the minimum variance you can have.